# Класс квадратного уравнения

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Объектом выступает квадратное уравнение. В классе должны быть такие методы: дополнительный конструктор, метод определения, имеет уравнение решения; метод решения уравнения. Возвращение результатов по методу решения уравнения должно выполняться через указатели.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class QuadEquation
{
    int a, b, c, D;
public:
    QuadEquation(void) = default;
    QuadEquation(int a_, int b_, int c_) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) {}
    ~QuadEquation(void) = default;

    void setMember(const int val, const char mem = 'a')
    {
        switch (mem)
        {
        case 'a':
            a = val;
            break;
        case 'b':
            b = val;
            break;
        case 'c':
            c = val;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    int decisions(void) { D = b * b - 4 * a * c; 
        return (D == 0 ? 1 : D > 0 ? 2 : 0); }

    void decide(double *x1, double *x2)
    {
        if (decisions() > 0)
        {
            *x1 = (-b + sqrt(double(D))) / (2 * a);
            *x2 = (-b - sqrt(double(D))) / (2 * a);
        }
        else 
        {
            *x1 = *x2 = nan("");
        }
    }
};
int main() {
    cout << "Calculating of quadratic equation" << endl;
    int a, b, c;
    double x1, x2;
    cout << "Enter a: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter b: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter c: " << endl;
    cin >> c;
    QuadEquation qe1(a, b, c);
    qe1.decide(&x1, &x2);
    cout << "equation have " << qe1.decisions() << " decisions in real numbers: " << endl << "x1 = " << x1 << endl << "x2 = " << x2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Вместо `std::endl` почти всегда достаточно `\n` и пробел тоже не нужен, так что можно выводить `Enter a:\n`. При инициализации везде, где можно, используйте фигурные скобки `{}`, а не круглые. И в конструкторе почему-то инициализируются `a`, `b`, `c`, но не `D`. `default: break;` подавляет предупреждения. Голые указатели в C++ коде почти не используют, лучше использовать ссылки или умные указатели

Comment: `Голые указатели в C++ коде почти не используют` - однако, Бьёрн топит за то, что надо =)

Answer (score 5):

1. `using namespace std;` обычно рассматривается как плохая практика.
2. У меня много вопросов к вашему методу `setMember`:

   2.1. Почему бы не сделать три отдельных сеттера `setCoefficientA`, `setCoefficientB` и `setCoefficientC`?

   Во-первых, дело в том, что в коде следует минимизировать количество возможных состояний вашей программы. Когда вы через значение аргумента `m` решаете, в какое поле записать значение, то количество возможных состояний вашей программы значительно увеличивается. Если же ввести три отдельных сеттера, то количество состояний становится *гораздо* меньше.

   Этот аргумент может казаться натянутым в данном конкретном случае, потому что программа очень короткая, но в больших и сложных системах очень важно уменьшать количество возможных состояний системы: отладка становится проще, реализация concurrency становится проще, сложность кода уменьшается. Почитайте про парадигму функционального программирования, где состояния нет вообще<sup>†</sup>.

   2.2. Вы задаете стандартное значение для `m`, т. е. следующий код устанавливает значение поля `a`:

   ```
   qe.setMember(100);
   ```

   Знаете что? При взгляде на код максимально не очевидно, что он делает то, что делает. Старайтесь писать код так, что было максимально понятно, что и за чем он делает.

   Дело в том, что единообразие — одно из свойств простой системы. Если я знаю, что я могу установить коэффициент `b` вот так

   ```
    qe.setMember(100, 'b');
   ```

   то предполагаю, что остальные коэффициенты устанавливаются точно также, единообразно:

   ```
    qe.setMember(200, 'a');
    qe.setMember(300, 'c');
   ```

   А когда я вижу

   ```
   qe.setMember(100);
   ```

   что я должен думать? Пусть лучше код будет немного длиннее, но единообразнне.
3. Переименуйте ваши методы подходящим образом:

   ```
   decisions → rootsCount
   decide → solve или findRoots
   ```

   Дело в том, что в английском языке „decisions“ — это не «решения» [квадратного уравнения], а „decide“ — это не «решить» [квадратное уравнение]. Т. е. у этих слов совсем другой контекст использования.
4. Проверяйте аргументы на валидность. Конкретно — в функции `decide` в качестве `x1` и `x2` могут передать нулевые указатели, разыменование которых приведет к неопределенному поведению.
5. Старайтесь объявлять переменные как можно ближе к месту их использования.

   Вы в коде объявляете переменные `x1`, `x2`, которые используются только спустя 6 строк. Их можно абсолютно безболезненно «спустить» к вызову `decide`:

   ```
   int a, b, c;

   std::cout << "Enter a: " << std::endl;
   std::cin >> a;
   std::cout << "Enter b: " << std::endl;
   std::cin >> b;
   std::cout << "Enter c: " << std::endl;
   std::cin >> c;

   QuadEquation qe1(a, b, c);

   double x1, x2;
   qe1.decide(&x1, &x2);
   ```

   Это позволяет сразу видеть для чего эти переменные нужны и не держать их в голове, пока читаешь все 6 строк, в которых они вообще не используются.

Answer (score 3):

1. Сложные вычисления (`sqrt(D)`, например) лучше записывать в переменные, а не считать каждый раз.
2. Советую придерживаться одного стиля во всем коде, а иначе он становится неудобочитаемым.
   С учетом сказанного выше, предлагаю такой код (менял только класс):

```
class QuadEquation
{
    double a, b, c, D;
public:
    QuadEquation(void) = default;
    QuadEquation(double a_, double b_, double c_) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) {}
    ~QuadEquation(void) = default;

    void setMember(const int val, const char mem = 'a')
    {
        switch (mem)
        {
            case 'a':
                a = val;
                break;
            case 'b':
                b = val;
                break;
            case 'c':
                c = val;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    int decisions(void) 
    { 
        D = b * b - 4 * a * c; 
        return (D == 0 ? 1 : D > 0 ? 2 : 0); 
    }

    void decide(double *x1, double *x2)
    {
        int d = decisions();
        if (d > 0)
        {
            double s_D = sqrt(D);
            *x1 = (-b + s_D) / (2 * a);
            *x2 = (-b - s_D) / (2 * a);
        }
        else 
        {
            *x1 = *x2 = nan("");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: У вас коэффициенты стали `double`, а в конструкторе — все еще `int`.

Comment: Ветка `else {*x1 = *x2 = nan("");}` — недостижима.

Comment: Сравнение `D == 0` тоже выглядит не очень (`D` имеет тип `double`).

Comment: Сравнивают с эпсилоном обычно. А вместо `(double) 0` достаточно `0.` или `0.0`

Comment: Ну и (1) вообще нужно убрать, код прекрасно решит уравнение с `D == 1`.

Comment: @eanmos исправил замечание про типы.

Comment: @wololo понял ошибку, исправил

Answer (score 2):

Я бы делал коэффициенты `double`, коэффициенты менял с возвратом ссылки на класс для цепочек, сделал бы ленивое вычисление (отсюда `mutable` члены), возвращал бы кортеж, чтоб было понятно, сколько корней (у меня -1 — бесконечно много корней).

А основные усилия надо направить на максимальную точность и все возможные варианты соотношения коэффициентов (например, что будет с вашей программой при `a == 0`?)). То, что сделал я, не занимает и половины всего возможного, но тем не менее... Там — непаханое поле :(

Словом, примерно

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class QEqu
{
    double a_,b_,c_;
    mutable tuple<int,double,double> res;
    mutable bool solved = false;
public:
    QEqu(double a = 0.0, double b = 0.0, double c = 0.0):a_(a),b_(b),c_(c) {}
    QEqu(const QEqu&)             = default;
    ~QEqu()                       = default;
    QEqu& operator =(const QEqu&) = default;
    QEqu& a(double aa) { a_ = aa; solved = false; return *this; }
    double a() const   { return a_; }
    QEqu& b(double aa) { b_ = aa; solved = false; return *this; }
    double b() const   { return b_; }
    QEqu& c(double aa) { c_ = aa; solved = false; return *this; }
    double c() const   { return c_; }

    std::tuple<int,double,double> solve() const;
};

tuple<int,double,double> QEqu::solve() const
{
    int count = 0;
    double x1 = nan(""), x2 = nan("");
    if (!solved)
    {
        if (a_ == 0.0)
        {
            if (b_ != 0.0)
            {
                x1 = -c_/b_;
                count = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (c_ == 0.0) count = -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c_ == 0.0)
            {
                x1 = 0.0;
                x2 = -b_/a_;
                count = 2;
            }
            else if (b_ == 0.0)
            {
                double d = -c_/a_;
                if (d >= 0)
                {
                    x1 = sqrt(d);
                    x2 = -x1;
                    count = 2;
                }
            } else
            {
                double d = b_*b_ - 4*a_*c_;
                if (d >= 0.0)
                {
                    if (b_ > 0)
                    {
                        x1 = (-b_ - sqrt(d))/2/a_;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x1 = (-b_ + sqrt(d))/2/a_;
                    }
                    x2 = a_*x1/c_;
                    count = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        solved = true;
        res = make_tuple(count,x1,x2);
    }
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QEqu q;
    cout << "Roots: " << get<0>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<1>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<2>(q.solve()) << endl;
    q.c(1);
    cout << "Roots: " << get<0>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<1>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<2>(q.solve()) << endl;
    q.b(2);
    cout << "Roots: " << get<0>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<1>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<2>(q.solve()) << endl;
    q.a(4).b(0).c(-8);
    cout << "Roots: " << get<0>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<1>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<2>(q.solve()) << endl;
    q.a(0.001).b(100).c(0);
    cout << "Roots: " << get<0>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<1>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<2>(q.solve()) << endl;
    q.c(0.001);
    cout << "Roots: " << get<0>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<1>(q.solve()) << " -- " << get<2>(q.solve()) << endl;

}
```